# Short story about a boy who chants, 'Rain, rain go away' - NOT Asimov's story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Does anyone know the author of this?

When I was a kid in the 1970s, I read a wonderful short story about a boy who chants 'rain, rain go away, come again some other day' whenever it rains on a day he wants to be outside.  The rain always stops.   Years go by, and he continues his mantra whenever the rain inconveniences him.  Eventually of course, his trick stops working, and the rains become a deluge, causing flooding, crop destruction, etc all over the world.   He eventually realizes:  'some other day' had finally come.

It's not Asimov's story of that title, nor Bradbury's 'There will come soft rains' or his 'The Long Rain'.

Comment: Until "deluge" I was expecting to answer "Peanuts"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This sounds like "[Rain, rain go away](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62677)", a short story by Harlan Ellison first published in 1956. As in the question, a man has the ability to cause rain to go away by saying the nursery rhyme:

> Sometimes I wish I were a duck, mused Hobert Krouse. Trapped in a
> dismal job, in a perpetually rain-drenched city, Hobert occasionally
> intones the childhood incantation, with generally successful results.

Eventually all the postponed rain arrives in one go when "some other day" arrives.

Comment: THANK  YOU!!!  Yes, that's it!   I remember the tone of the writing, and for some reason didn't connect it to Harlan Ellison.  Thanks so much!